# How do I block videos by keyword on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

For example, I want to block videos that contain the word `cat` in the title. I also do not want the blocked videos appearing in:

- Recommended Channels tab
- Recommended/related videos
- Search results

How can I accomplish this?

I found these tools to be somewhat useful.

1. [Fiddler for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fiddler/hkknfnifmbannmgkdliadghepbneplka?hl=en)  - very good;will do the trick if some superuser who knows how to fiddle can help me out
2. [video-blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk/related?hl=en) - somewhat ok;problem is it blocks youtube thumbnails after a slight delay for more detail

   Q:Why do I see a blimp of the videos from my blocked channels when loading a page on YouTube?

   A:To prevent slower page loading times, this extension hides the videos after they appear on the page. Otherwise, the extension would have to filter everything on the page before it shows anything to you, which could result in a slower loading time of the page and an unpleasant experience.

Taken from comments: By TheFireHawkDelta

> It blocks the channels I hate that Youtube wants to cram down my throat. My only problem with it is I can't find a way to block a specific series, so I had to block Machinima entirely".

Answer (score 3):

Try the **Video Blocker** extension/add-on:

- [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk)
- [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/video-blocker/)

Its purpose is just that: to block an entire channel or videos by certain keywords in their titles.