# How do I disable channel recommendation on YouTube about a particular topic?

Tags: youtube

Disabling channel recommendation completely is not possible on YouTube but I am wondering if there's a way to prevent YouTube recommending something I just don't want to see, say [Bollywood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollywood).

I tried to change my location; to some other country (Bosnia and Herzegovina) which I think has to do with football [I'm from India]. I was getting a lot of sports channel recommendation which wasn't a bother but somehow Youtube has figured out where I'm from and the hot channels are gradually finding their way back.

**Summing up:** How do I disable channel recommendation on YouTube about a particular topic?

Comment: Seems similar: [How do I block videos by keyword on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66167/354)

Comment: Not at all. The asked specifically requests blocking *channel recommendations* by particular topic, not *video recommendations* by keyword, although the procedure outlined might very well have an effect on both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a shared computer or device to watch YouTube videos, make sure you're logged on to your Google account, so the recommendation algorithm loads your own viewing history.

If you are logged in to your Google account, you may want to review your YouTube viewing history, either completely disabling it or deleting records of any videos you (or somebody else, inadvertently logged into your account) might have watched in the the past on the topics you don't want to see in your recommendations.

The YouTube viewing history,  is an important signal to the recommendation algorithm that "follows you" throughout the different devices you may  use while using YouTube.

All too frequently, one forgets to log off, especially on a family shared computer and it is a common occurrence that someone in your household uses the same device to watch YouTube without logging you out, thus skewing the statistics the algorithm uses to predict the channels you might be interested in.

To either disable or review your YouTube Watching history,

1. log in to your Google account at https://accounts.google.com
   [image: my account]
2. Under **Personal info & privacy**, click on **activity controls** 
   [image]
3. Scroll down to the bottom and you will see options to disable and review your YouTube search and watch history. 
   [image][image]
4. You can disable those signals by switching them off, you will get, then recommendations that rely more on your current session and location, however my advice is to review the history, where you can delete any records of any searches and watched videos that may be skewing your statistics. 
   [image][image]

Hope this helps.